# migrate list with lookup filed from sharepoint 2010 to sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration

How can I migrate list with lookup fields from sharepoint 2010 to sharepoint online

Answer (score 0):

First, we need to have an inventory of all lookup lists in the environment - probably we can use the ShareGate tool for this reporting purpose.

Then, using any of the third-party migration tools ShareGate, Metalogix, etc. migrate the parent list (**dependent list**) first then migrate the **main** list.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [**SharePoint Migration Tool**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/introducing-the-sharepoint-migration-tool), which allows you to migrate lists with lookup fields.

You will need to migrate all lists at once so that it carries the lookup connection from SharePoint on-premises to Online.

Individual migration for lists with lookup fields is not supported for the time being.